# pip cannot find module that is in pypi

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have created a python module, `i2cdev`.

- pypi link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=pkg_edit&name=i2cdev
- git link: https://github.com/cloudformdesign/i2cdev

When I try to install it through pip, I get that it cannot find it:

```
$ pip3 search "i2cdev"  # finds it fine
i2cdev                    - Simple I2C Library for linux
$ pip3 install i2cdev
Collecting i2cdev
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement i2cdev
  No distributions at all found for i2cdev
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wow, I'm an idiot. Apparently you have to use `setup.py sdist upload` to actually upload the code onto python. I thought just registering it was enough.

Answer (score 2):

You have to setup download link for the `tarball/zip` file which is uploaded.You can check it by

```
http://pypi.python.org/simple/<package name>
```

Because pip searches in this above `url`.If There is no download links, You have to add `download_link` as `metadata`.That is something like

in `setup.py`

```
setup(...,
     download_url = 'http://pypi/path/to/package.tar.gz',

     )
```

I found out, your's is

```
https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/i/i2cdev/i2cdev-1.2.4.tar.gz
```

Comment: I wonder if this would have worked as well... I think the solution I posted is the best though because it will keep track of version information. Thanks though!